# Can't create user on Bitnami Dokuwiki

Tags: docker, bitnami, dokuwiki

I've created a Bitnami Dokuwiki Docker container on my Mac using:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-dokuwiki/master/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up -d
```

I can connect to it in my browser, and there is a login link, but no way I can find to create a user.

Is there a default user, hopefully an admin user? Or do I need to create a user another way?

Comment: @Rup Thank you, that worked. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default login is superuser, bitnami1.

It sets up this superuser account when you initially create the container. You can change the username and password it uses by passing environment variables [DOKUWIKI_USERNAME and DOKUWIKI_PASSWORD](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-dokuwiki#environment-variables) to docker with -e.